# How can I copy data from specific worksheet of a workbook to another with the same worksheet name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 7 productivity files which I need to copy the data from the sheet titled worktracker and paste these in the worktracker sheet in the masterfile, but I'm getting:

> Run-time error 1004
> Method Range of object_Worksheet failed.

[image: paste image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim file As String
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Set wbMaster = Workbooks("WorkTracker_Master.xlsm")
       
    Set rng = wbMaster.Sheets("WorkTracker").Range("A4:W4")

    myPath = "\\BMGSMP1012\GBDMC_Team$\GBDM_ContentManagement\+CM_Reports\Productivity Reports\FY18\"
    file = Dir(myPath & "*.xls*")
    While (file <> "")
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & file)
        
        lastrow = wb.Worksheets("WorkTracker").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn = wb.Worksheets("WorkTracker").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Range(Cell(2, 1)(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        
        erow = WorkTracker.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination = Worksheets("WorkTracker").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 4))

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Set wb = Nothing

            file = Dir
    Wend

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please paste your actual code into the question - `Range(Cell(2, 1)(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy` is invalid syntax so the code won't run.  So you won't be getting a 1004 error with that code.  And also tell us which line of the (actual) code gives the error.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K...I did paste the code using {}...sorry im still new at this

Comment: The line saying `Range(Cell(2, 1)(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy` is still there - is that how it actually is in your real code?

Comment: @YowE3K yes...i copied that bit from a youtube tutorial earlier

Comment: Well, that won't compile, so I can't see how you are getting a 1004 error in code that won't run at all.

Comment: i see.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify all your objects, a comfortable and easy way, is to seperate each `Workbook` by using a nested `With` statement.

Also, as @YowE3K already mentioned  in the comments above, you have a syntax error when defining the copied `Range`.

Try the code below, inside your `While (file <> "")` loop, after you `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & file)` :

```
With wb.Worksheets("WorkTracker")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Copy
End With

With wbMaster.Worksheets("WorkTracker")
    ' get first empty row in column "A"
    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    ' paste in the first empty row
    .Range("A" & erow).PasteSpecial
End With

wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
Set wb = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Shai Rado...i copied your code and placed it into the code as per your advice...but it seems it's only copying the headers instead of the entries from cell A4:W4 onwards? sorry still really new at coding vba

Comment: @agatha  check your lastRow variable value

Comment: thanks! i am at a loss as to how to update the code actually...i just copied the code from an online tutorial earlier